# Sails.js: Angular: my controller is not executing

Tags: html, angularjs, sails.js

I am using Sails and I dont get my angular controllers to execute. This is my layout.ejs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%=typeof title == 'undefined' ? 'New Sails App' : title%></title>

    <!-- Viewport mobile tag for sensible mobile support -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">




    <!--STYLES-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/importer.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/style.css">
    <!--STYLES END-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.SAILS_LOCALS = { 
        me: <%- JSON.stringify(me||null) %>
      }; 
    </script>


  </head>

  <body ng-app="containers">
    <%- partial('./partials/navigation.ejs') %>
    <%- body %>




    <!--TEMPLATES-->

    <!--TEMPLATES END-->
    <!--SCRIPTS-->
    <script src="/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/dependencies/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/dependencies/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/dependencies/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/dependencies/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/controllers/adminPageController.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/controllers/navPageController.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/controllers/ordersPageController.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/controllers/welcomePageController.js"></script>
    <!--SCRIPTS END-->




  </body>
</html>
```

none of the controllers that I have implemented get executed, I will paste the simplest code example. This is the first html that goes into `<%- body%>` when I run sails lift:

```
<div ng-controller="welcomePageController">


</div>
```

and this is the controller called above:

```
angular.module('containers').controller('welcomePageController', [ '$scope', '$http', function( $scope, $http ) {
    console.log("hola");
      // set-up loading state
      $scope.loginForm = {
        loading: false
      };

      $scope.me = window.SAILS_LOCALS.me;

    }]);
```

The thing is I don't even get the log in my console. Also if I try to put something like `<label>{{loginForm.loading}}</label>` inside the html, I only get to print exactly that, {{loginForm.loading}}.

Comment: do you use angular-route ? you never call your controller

Comment: what? isnt my controller called by ng-controller? I'm new to angular, could you explain a little more pleas?